# Unknown android attribute on android studio 3

Tags: android-studio

I have base_lib project make by eclipse. Now i import to android studio 3
It have a error as below. Plz help me, thank

Error:Execution failed for task ':base_lib:processDebugResources'.

> Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'